# How to separate POS from words

Tags: regex, r, pos-tagger

Need to create an text sparce matrix (DTM) for classification. To prepare the text, first I need to eliminate (separate) the POS-tags the text. My guess was to do it like below. I'm new to R and don't now how to negate a REGEX (see below NOT!).

```
text <- c("wenn/KOUS ausläuft/VVFIN ./$.", "Kommt/VVFIN vor/PTKVZ ;/$.", "-RRB-/TRUNC Durch/APPR und/KON", "man/PIS zügig/ADJD ./$.", "empfehlung/NN !!!/NE")
```

My guess how it could work:

```
(POSs <- regmatches(text, gregexpr('[[:punct:]]*/[[:alpha:][:punct:]]*', text)))
[[1]]
[1] "/KOUS"  "/VVFIN" "./$."  

[[2]]
[1] "/VVFIN" "/PTKVZ" ";/$."  

[[3]]
[1] "-/TRUNC" "/APPR"   "/KON"   

[[4]]
[1] "/PIS"  "/ADJD" "./$." 

[[5]]
[1] "/NN"    "!!!/NE"
```

But don't konw how to negate the expression like:

```
#                          VVV
(texts <- regmatches(text, NOT!(gregexpr('[[:punct:]]*/[[:alpha:][:punct:]]*', text))))
[[1]]
[1] "wenn"  "ausläuft"  

[[2]]
[1] "Kommt" "vor"  

[[3]]
[1] "Durch"   "und"   

[[4]]
[1] "man"  "zügig"

[[5]]
[1] "empfehlung"
```

Comment: To eliminate the tags, why not just search for them and replace with nothing? eg: `gsub('[[:punct:]]*/[[:alpha:][:punct:]]*','', text)`

Comment: @rawr Thank you, nice :) . As mentioned I'm very new here, however the output is not as useful as the `regmatches`-variant. Do you know how to refine the code in order to get the desired output?

Comment: @rawr Think I found a way, paste them back together and make the split later. Thank you! A+ If you know a method/ that's more direct would be grateful if you to post it here because my is rather a work around (would vote it as the right answer..). Thank you and best regards!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to eliminate the tags by, searching for POS-tags and replacing them with `''` (i.e. empty text):

```
text <- c("wenn/KOUS ausläuft/VVFIN ./$.", "Kommt/VVFIN vor/PTKVZ ;/$.", "-RRB-/TRUNC Durch/APPR und/KON", "man/PIS zügig/ADJD ./$.", "empfehlung/NN !!!/NE")

(textlist <- strsplit(paste(gsub('[[:punct:]]*/[[:alpha:][:punct:]]*','', text), sep=' '), " "))
[[1]]
[1] "wenn"     "ausläuft"

[[2]]
[1] "Kommt" "vor"  

[[3]]
[1] "-RRB"  "Durch" "und"  

[[4]]
[1] "man"   "zügig"

[[5]]
[1] "empfehlung"
```

With the friendly help of **rawr**